# I want to use okhttp to put file to server

Tags: java, android

when i post a file to server,i try to get the result from server when the file is upload success,but when i did it,it throws an exception,there is my code

```
 call.enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {

            Log.e("upload", "upload fail" + e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
            removeRequest(tag);
            listener.onUploadFail();
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
            try {


                Log.e("upload", "upload success" + response.body().string());
                listener.onUploadSuccess(response.message());

                removeRequest(tag);
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }


    });
```

there is the exception

```
05-23 16:37:24.047 19334-19462/com.gzkit.DianJianPlatform W/System.err: java.lang.IllegalStateException: closed
05-23 16:37:24.047 19334-19462/com.gzkit.DianJianPlatform W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.Http1xStream$FixedLengthSource.read(Http1xStream.java:378)
05-23 16:37:24.047 19334-19462/com.gzkit.DianJianPlatform W/System.err:     at okio.Buffer.writeAll(Buffer.java:956)
05-23 16:37:24.047 19334-19462/com.gzkit.DianJianPlatform W/System.err:     at okio.RealBufferedSource.readByteArray(RealBufferedSource.java:92)
05-23 16:37:24.047 19334-19462/com.gzkit.DianJianPlatform W/System.err:     at okhttp3.ResponseBody.bytes(ResponseBody.java:83)
05-23 16:37:24.047 19334-19462/com.gzkit.DianJianPlatform W/System.err:     at okhttp3.ResponseBody.string(ResponseBody.java:109)
05-23 16:37:24.047 19334-19462/com.gzkit.DianJianPlatform W/System.err:     at com.gzkit.workmap.kithttpmanager.core.KitHttpManager$4.onResponse(KitHttpManager.java:1084)
05-23 16:37:24.047 19334-19462/com.gzkit.DianJianPlatform W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:133)
05-23 16:37:24.047 19334-19462/com.gzkit.DianJianPlatform W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
05-23 16:37:24.047 19334-19462/com.gzkit.DianJianPlatform W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
05-23 16:37:24.047 19334-19462/com.gzkit.DianJianPlatform W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
05-23 16:37:24.047 19334-19462/com.gzkit.DianJianPlatform W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: You have three statements in the try block. Which one causes the exception? Is it the catch block in your code that you are talking about?

Comment: You should tell if onFailure or onResponse is triggered to begin with.

Comment: I try to get the result from ' response.body().string() '  when i uploaded file success,but it throw the exception

Comment: Then you should investigate that response in a different way. Use .message(). Or remove that log statement. You are not doing anything with the response furter.

Comment: I try to use response.body().message() ,but the message is only contain 'ok' not any useful information